# why sometimes I use SVG pictures as background images in my React Project , they may be blur in IOS device?

Tags: javascript, ios, svg

I am a frontend developer in my university,I make a React project for my school .I use the background-image property in CSS to import my background image, and the format of my accompanying image is SVG，but it may be blur in IOS devices,so how can I solve the problem?

I try to change the format of the image to avif or png ,but they all failed,even be blur in android device...
If you have a solution to my problem, please let me know. I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Probably it's a pixel density issue. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio